# Non-precise STM32F303VC Timer Clock

Tags: c, timer, embedded, clock, stm32

I'm using a timer 8 on STM32f3 discovery board to drive DAC sine wave generation. Here is my Timer configuration:

```
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef    timer;

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APB1Periph_TIM6, ENABLE );

TIM_TimeBaseStructInit( &timer );
timer.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
//Setting prescaler so that timer clock will be only 64000Hz
timer.TIM_Prescaler = 1125;
//Setting period so Timer will give signal of frequency 1000Hz
timer.TIM_Period = 10;
TIM_TimeBaseInit( TIM6, &timer );

//generate event when counter hits TIM_period value
TIM_SelectOutputTrigger(TIM6, TIM_TRGOSource_Update);

/* TIM2 enable counter */
TIM_Cmd(TIM6, ENABLE);
```

I assume that clock equals 72MHz.

When I measure sine wave frequeency, it shows 90Hz instead of 100Hz. When I calculate back the clock frequency of APB1 clock, it comes aout that it equals 64.8MHz which seems very strange. I did not change anything regarding lcock configuration settings, everything is default.

System clock core equals 72MHz (checked it using RCC_GetClocksFreq command).

Anyone got idea where this comes from?

Comment: _"I assume that clock equals 72MHz."_  You really need to _know_ - you cannot assume that.  It will be 72MHz _only_ if you have configured the PLL as such, and accurate _only_ if using an accurate external oscillator.  The internal HSE RC oscillator has a wide variation and is not temperature stable.  If using standard CMSIS start-up code, the PLL will be configured in system_stm32f3xx.c `SystemInit()`.  And the _nominal_ clock frequency will be stored in the global `SystemCoreClock`.

Comment: You might better also calculate your prescaler in terms of `SystemCoreClock` for or better yet the ABP1 clock frequency for portability to different clock configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HSI clock as source, here is the problem.

HSI clock is not accurate and can vary +- 10% at least.

Btw look at your comments.

```
Timer count clock = timer_input_clock / (prescaler_value + 1)
```

Your case

```
72000000 / 1126 = 63943Hz
```

With period of 10 you get:

```
tim_overflow_period = tim_clock / (period + 1)
```

in your case

```
63943 / 11 = 5813
```

If you set your prescaler to 1124 and period to 9, you will get better results.

```
timer_clock = 72000000 / (1124 + 1) = 64000
timer_overflow = 64000 / (9 + 1) = 6400
```

Do you have 64 samples of your DAC output signal?
I believe you use DMA for that.

if so, you should get 100Hz if you have external oscillator, otherwise you may not. Check app notes regarding HSI oscillator calibration.

Comment: Discovery boards should have crystals

Comment: Correct. But did you enable it in software?

Comment: Not mine question ;)